# Why I am not getting the Hello Tensorflow output?

Tags: tensorflow

I couldn't get the output Hello Tesorflow?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do get your output... See the last line...

Maybe it is a good idea to check your installation/reinstall Tensorflow.